# Sprite cortado diagonalmente em Unity 5

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

Criei um jogo em Unity 5 (diretamente para Android) (seguindo o seguinte [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HT55YdzQrtk&list=PLOFacakspTDJSqQm_hdPD1SqYDC6hopR4)) porém quando o executo no Android os Sprites ficam cortados diagonalmente como a foto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **OBS:** Os teste no ambiente da Unity 5 ocorrem perfeitamente sem erros.
>
> **OBS2:** O app foi testado em 2 Androids diferentes (4.4.2 e 5.0) (tiveram o 
>   erro em questão).
>
> **OBS3:** Todas as telas possuem este corte diagonal.

Main Camera Inspector: [Link](http://postimg.org/image/ujvvbcmkf/)
Canvas: [Link](http://postimg.org/image/z9lszydkv/)
Button Theme: [Link](http://postimg.org/image/6hf1gh5xb/)
Button Play: [Link](http://postimg.org/image/a2awzpagv/)
Background: [Link](http://postimg.org/image/zcypup8ql/)
GameController: [Link](http://postimg.org/image/oengcik59/)
ThemePanel: [Link](http://postimg.org/image/jdg2b5cot/)

Pergunta relaciona no Unity Answers: [Link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1005726/sprite-is-diagonally-cut-off-when-on-android-but-w.html)

Projeto no Github: [Link](https://github.com/ricardohenriq/timequiz)

> A solução dada pelo GabrielZulian funcionou porém isso me levantou algumas dúvidas: qual o motivo de cortar diagonalmente ? Não deveria ficar totalmente oculto ?, porque nas telas Game/Scene da Unity é exibido normalmente? Verifiquei também que este problema não ocorre na versão anterior ao 5 da unity.

Comment: Olá Ricardo. Cara, não leve a mal o comentário, mas este site não é um fórum. Fazer comentários em outras perguntas pra chamar a atenção para esta não é um procedimento muito correto. Sobre esta pergunta, você chegou a executar o APK em um simulador ou em outro dispositivo pra ter certeza que o problema não está no equipamento específico?

Comment: @LuizVieira Em 2 Androids diferentes (4.4.2 e 5.0)

Comment: Bom, seria importante editar a questão para adicionar essa informação, ok? Também, poste o trecho do código em que o HUD é montado. Se você facilitar, muitas pessoas podem se interessar em ajudar. Você não deveria esperar que tenham paciência de assistir a todo o tutorial ou procurar no seu código onde o HUD está montado pra tentar achar o problema.

Comment: Eu estou de férias, então não tenho o ambiente de desenvolvimento pra sequer testar. Mas eu diria que se o problema não for de algo estar sendo desenhado na frente do HUD, pode ser algo da versão do sistema operacional, ou da forma como você empacota o Atlas (o tile sheet que vc usa para os componentes do HUD). Procure alterar essa imagem pra fazer alguns testes e ver se o resultado muda (pois pode te ajudar).

Comment: @LuizVieira estou com dificuldades em encontrar estas informações que citou, onde elas ficam armazenas ?

Comment: Outra coisa: vc verificou as informações da resposta existente no Unity Answers que vc mesmo menciona? Lá tem algumas ideias. A verificação depende de como você montou o HUD. É um GUITexture? Vc pode tentar reimportar a imagem do tile sheet (como a resposta lá do Unity Answers sugere). Fica dentro do seu projeto.

Comment: @LuizVieira O HUD é a interface do jogo? se sim cada interface é uma cena (Titulo.unity)

Comment: Isso mesmo: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HUD_(jogo_eletr%C3%B4nico)

Comment: Olá Ricardo. Para poder ajudar precisamos saber o que de fato você fez / deixou de fazer.
Poderia, por favor, postar:  
- o inspector dos componentes em que esse problema aparece - propriedades dos sprites - e as configurações da tua exportação para Android dentro no Unity. Pode ser um print screen mesmo.

Sobre HUD no unity: preferencialmente use o canvas, uma nova cena para cada elemento do HUD vai sobrecarregar a memória e vai te dar dor de cabeça.

Comment: Lembrando que interface contabiliza toda a interação que vc tem com o jogo, entradas e saídas.

Comment: Olá @Nils, adicionei os printscreen dos inspectors principais, (irei adicionei os dos objetos filhos agora), existe alguma forma de encontrar os inspectors no formato de código?

Comment: @Ricardo adiciona as imagens aqui no próprio stackoverflow, assim utilizadores com o mesmo problema podem ver as imagens, porque não serão apagadas.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes São muitas imagens, elas farão com que a pergunta fique muito extensa (adicionarei mais em breve), mas para perpetuar as imagens estarei as enviando para o github e trocarei os links.

Comment: @Ricardo as imagens não tornarão a pergunta extensa, elas são um auxilio para quem vai ajuda-lo, inclusive o stackoverflow incentiva essa prática.

Comment: Não sei se irá ajudar, mas já tentou aumentar o "order in layer" do cavas? Além disso tentar desativar o seu background e compilar para Android sem ele, para ver se o problema persiste. Penso que seu background está a causar o problema.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes esta mudança não resolveu :- <

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema parece estar relacionado com o eixo Z do seu background. Tente colocar a depth position (Z) dele para 1.

Comment: Funcionou mas qual o motivo de cortar diagonalmente ? Não deveria ficar totalmente oculto ?, porque nas telas Game/Scene da Unity é exibido normalmente?

Comment: Verifiquei também que este problema não ocorre na versão anterior ao 5 da unity